# Second Y-Axis in Highcharts linked to specific data series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

i have 6 series (lines) within one chart categorized by date. one of the series has a way higher max point than all the others making them disappear into a a single line at the bottom. the data is generated from different reports with series in different order but mostly with the same data mixed together with variable data. 
i want to add a second y-axis on the right to keep that one single series separated from all the other data but i need a way to tell highcharts to take a specific series which name i know. series.name would be always the same. is there any way to accomplish that?

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you define "y" axes -

```
yAxis: [{},{},{}] 
// so "yAxis" is just an array of y-axis-objects (i.e. yAxis[0], yAxis[1]...)
```

And you can tell Highcharts which one of these y axes you want your series be associated with as follows -

```
series: [{yAxis: 1}, {yAxis: 2}, {}]
```

So, your first series will be associated with `yAxis[1]`, second with `yAxis[2]` and the third by default with `yAxis[0]`.

Check out the API ref on [yAxis](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis) and [series](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series).

You can also see the demo of dual-axes [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes). There you can click the "View Options" to see how the `options` object is configured.